# Cocoapods no longer builds project after update?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

After updating to the latest version of cocoapods I can no longer generate the project. Uninstalling the latest version and going back to the older version doesn't resolve the issue either.

**The exact code was working fine before updating cocoapods**

[!] The `MyApplication [App Store]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApplication/Pods-MyApplication.app store.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

```
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or

- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Comment: @jww thanks a lot that solved the problem. Can you add your comment as the answer so that I can accept?

Comment: OK, done. I kind of feel bad for doing it, but the question does need an answer for future visitors.

Comment: Why feel bad? It answers the question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `- Remove the build settings from the target.`

Open the project in Xcode. Select the ***Project*** (not a *Target*). Then ensure `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` are acceptable. Now, for each ***Target*** (not *Project*), visit the same setting. If its **BOLD**, then its overridden.

To remove the override, select the setting so its highlighted (i.e., white text with blue background) and then press <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>. The bold text should go away, and the Target setting will return to inheriting from the Project setting.

In the example below, *Product Name* is overriden for the *Target*, while *Wrapper Extension* is highlighted. (Neither of these apply to your problem - they just show what to look for under Xcode).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Removing this redundant part of my `.xcodeproj` file fixed this issue:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)",
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks",
            );
```