# "missing from working copy" build issues when upgrading to Cocoapods 1.0+

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

Cocoapods is no longer generating all the required headers in Pods/Headers/Private and thus causing hundreds of "missing from working copy" build issues.

The issue started happening when I upgraded from:

- Xcode 7
- Cocoapods pre-1.0 (not sure which version I had)
- OSX El Capitan
- platform ios 7.0

to

- Xcode 8 Beta 6
- Cocoapods 1.0.1
- macOS Sierra 10.12 Beta
- platform ios 8.0

My "Pods/Target Support Files" folder has 35 pods, but my "Pods/Headers/Private" and "Pods/Headers/Private" have only 4 pods each.

I tried adding "$(inherited)" to my build settings and many other of the suggested fixes on stackoverflow and cocoapods' website with no success.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Meow' do
use_frameworks!

pod "AFNetworking"
pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C'
pod "MMMaterialDesignSpinner"
pod "JMImageCache"
pod “AWSCore”
pod “AWSSNS”
pod “AWSMobileAnalytics”
pod ”SSToolkit”, '~> 2.0.0'
pod ”TTTAttributedLabel”
pod ”M13ProgressSuite”
pod ”SSKeychain”
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod "Flurry-iOS-SDK"
pod "TPKeyboardAvoiding"
pod "UITextView+Placeholder"
pod "UIReadMoreLabel"
pod "RTLabel"
pod "HexColors"
pod "Branch"
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Mixpanel'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

target 'MeowTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end

end
```

Any help is super appreciated!
Henri

Comment: Have you heard of the scientific method?  Have you considered that it might be a good idea to upgrade one thing at a time in order to drastically narrow the scope on what actually broke your project?

Comment: You can't run Xcode 8 withour macOS Sierra - so those 2 come hand-in-hand. Xcode 8 won't allow you to build for anything under ios8 so that also is required. The only thing I can downgrade is cocoapods - which I tried. I tried downgrading to 0.39 and I still get missing header issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of digging and trial/error I figured it out. The root issue was the upgrade from Cocoapods 0.39 to 1.0+.

You can solve this by following theses steps:

1. Remove any build settings you're overriding by following this: [Cocoapods no longer builds project after update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070241/cocoapods-no-longer-builds-project-after-update)
2. Downgrade from v1.0+ to 0.39 following this: [How to downgrade or install an older version of Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/how-to-downgrade-or-install-an-older-version-of-cocoapods)
3. Delete the Pods folder, the Pod lock file
4. Add this line to the top of your Podfile
   `source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"`
5. Run pod install
6. Run cmd+k in Xcode and compile.

More Resources:

http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/

Answer (score 0):

To me @cybermach answer is partially helpful.

The full answer is:
1- Downgrade the CocoaPods from 1.0 to 0.39 using this link:
[Install old cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233445/install-old-cocoapods)

2- Then use this command "pod install" to again add the private headers.